# Mongoose delete a simple value from array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a document like this in mongo:

```
device: {
"device 1",
"device 2",
"device 3"
}
name: "name"
}
```

How can delete just one value in device from mongoose? i know it can be whit $pull but i dont have a reference for the elements

Thanks.

Comment: Your document is not a valid json. Would be helpful if you can update with a valid one and also post your expected output.

Answer (score 2):

pull

```
db.collection.update({
  name: "name"
},
{
  $pull: {
    device: {
      $eq: "device 2"
    }
  }
},
{
  multi: true
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/13yKNe46xit)